# How can I create a daily task that repeats every 15 mins EXCEPT between the hours of 12AM - 2AM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

Is it possible to create a scheduled task that runs every 15 min except for a few hours of the day.

E.g. A task that runs every 15 minutes except between the hours of 2PM & 4PM.

The reason I need to do this is because I have another task that writes to the same file once a day and takes 1 hour to parse/upload and I cannot have the 15 min task attempting to parse/upload while the larger one is working...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want to set the trigger to On a schedule to look like this below. The task will start at 4PM and continue until 2PM where it will stop for 2 hours, and continue again.
[image]

Comment: Yep, except make sure it is set to "Daily" instead of "One time".  Also take into account that it might run into the 2pm slot, and consider checking the "stop all running tasks at end of repetition duration."

Comment: @TheCleaner oops, forgot to click that before doing a screenshot. I'll update my post to reflect that.

Comment: @Cole - you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems Windows Server 2012 does not allow an option of 22h so you have 12h or 1 day and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In Windows server 2008 and higher you can assign multiple schedules to a task.  Create one that runs from midnight until 2pm, then another from 4pm until midnight.